# 2 neural net output as input of third neural net

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

Hi I am trying to make following scheme of neural net using either pytorch or keras but it i don't know how to do it, can any one help.

scheme:

[Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUHN3.png)

Comment: Hi, to get any useful answer, please post about what you have tried so far. Any particular piece of code that you are having problems with?

Comment: i have tried to make it with pytorch but i get an error in input out put :RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Byte but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'mat2'      the code is in here: https://pastebin.com/Y7d2Bniy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes a Keras Implementation using the functional API

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, concatenate

def createModel( inp_1_shape, inp_2_shape):
  first_input = Input(shape = (inp_1_shape,))
  first_dense = Dense(1, )(first_input)

  second_input = Input(shape = (inp_2_shape,))
  second_dense = Dense(1, )(second_input)

  merge = concatenate([first_dense, second_dense])
  merge = Dense(2, )(merge)
  merge = Dense(3, )(merge)
  merge = Dense(1, )(merge)

  model = Model(inputs=[first_input, second_input], outputs=merge)
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model
```

Just call this function and it will return a keras Model, you might need to double check the no of neurons in each layer, but other than that, you will be fine.

[image: Model usage]

Happy Training

Comment: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/ Go through Multi-input Multi-ouput part in this, if you still cannot figure it out, let me know.

Comment: i am trying to make an adding with this neural net , but the result is not ok, the loss is good but prediction is false